# Decoupling variable declaration and assignment in bash

Tags: bash

Bash here. I want to write a script that declares several variables, assigns them *different* values based on a conditional, and then uses them later on (whatever they were conditionally assigned to):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
$fizz
$buzz
$foo
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  fizz = "Jane Smith"
  buzz = true
  foo = 44
else
  fizz = "John Smith"
  buzz = false
  foo = 31
fi

# now do stuff with fizz, buzz and foobar regardless of what their values are
```

When I run this (`bash myscript.sh`) I get errors. Can anyone spot if I have a syntax error anywhere? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider running your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ and taking note of the errors.

Comment: No white space surrounding `=`. `$foo` is not a declaration, if it had a value it would be executed as a command. The if statement logic is fine, assuming you want Jane if the first arg is empty, and John if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your script:

1. a line with just `$variable` is not a declaration. That will be evaluated and expanded to an empty line (since your variables don't exist).
2. Bash does not allow spaces around the `=` sign

On declaring variables, you don't really need to do that, since bash won't give you an error if an variable doesn't exist - it will just expand to an empty string. If you really need to, you can use `variable=` (with nothing after the `=`) to set the variable to an empty string.

I'd suggest changing it to this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  fizz="Jane Smith"
  buzz=true
  foo=44
else
  fizz="John Smith"
  buzz=false
  foo=31
fi
```

By the way, keep in mind that `bash` has no concept of variable types - these are all strings, including `false`, `true`, `44`, etc.